# Cambiar Formato de un Json Angular-material

Tags: angular6, angular-material

estoy intentando conectarme a un endpoint, pero el json que recibe no es igual que que me genera en angular, el json que estoy es debido a que tengo un un `mat-select` para seleccionar varias opciones y se genera asi:

```
{  
   "email1":"mid@nd.com",
   "email2":"mid@nd.coma",
   "mobile1":"789456",
   "mobile2":"456123",
   "questions":[  
      "What is your father's name?",
      "What is your school's name?",
      "What brand was your first car?"
   ],
   "password":"Control@123"
}
```

El Json que recibe el endpoint es este

```
{  
   "email1":"mid@nd.com",
   "email2":"mid@nd.coma",
   "mobile1":"789456",
   "mobile2":"456123",
   "question1": "What is your father's name?",
   "question1": "What is your school's name?",
    "question1":"What brand was your first car?",
   "password":"Control@123"
}
```

Si alguien sabe como sacar o como personalizar esto se lo agradeceria un monton.

Comment: Hola, no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. ¿Quién genera el JSON?. ¿El endpoint recibe lo que debería? Debes ser un poco más específico. Trata de mostrar el código de cómo generas el JSON, de cómo lo recibes. Luego explica el error, cuál es el comportamiento deseado y cuál es el resultado obtenido. Saludos.

Comment: el front end estoy generando el json para enviarlo al endpiont